# SymfonyTestsListener does not exist on PHP Unit Test

Tags: testing

When I try to run a unit test I get an error that SymfonyTestsListener does not exist.  Am I running this correctly?

```
../../vendor/bin/phpunit -c phpunit.xml ../modules/custom/my_module/

Class "Symfony\Bridge\PhpUnit\SymfonyTestsListener" does not exist
```

I am using PHPUnit 6.5.13.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Had a similar issue:
Solved it by adding the "symfony/phpunit-bridge": "^3.4.3" library.

Answer (score 5):

Removing the line below in `phpunit.xml` fixes my issue:

```
<!-- The Symfony deprecation listener has to come after the Drupal listener -->
<listener class="Symfony\Bridge\PhpUnit\SymfonyTestsListener">
</listener>
```

Not sure if this will cause any issues.

Comment: Thanks @albertski this worked for me but don't know why yet...

Comment: Where to comment this? is this line not really required?

Comment: This is in `phpunit.xml`.

Comment: @ARUN, I needed to modify [web/]core/phpunit.xml.dist.

Comment: Removing this line will only disable the deprecation listener, the correct answer here is provided by @dragu-alexandru.

Comment: "Do we need this screw?" "Nahhhh"

Answer (score 4):

Although the approved answer here shows the exact package that is needed what users may be looking for is to require the "drupal/core-dev" package which contains the needed "symfony/phpunit-bridge" as a dependency.

Comment: If you are doing things in Drupal, I think this is the answer you are looking for. And you probably want to put it in the require-dev section of composer.json:
"require-dev": {
    "drupal/core-dev": "^9"
  },

Answer (score 0):

Try using [symfony/phpunit-bridge](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/phpunit_bridge.html):

`composer require --dev symfony/phpunit-bridge`

This will install the phpunit-bridge that is used with phpunit, it fixed the issue for me.