# What is the recommended way for using PHPUnit?

Tags: testing, 9

Installing Drupal 9 with the *drupal/recommended-project* Composer package ships without PHPUnit. Why? (In Drupal 8 it is included. The [documentation](https://www.drupal.org/docs/automated-testing/phpunit-in-drupal/running-phpunit-tests) only tells about Drupal 8.)

Which version of PHPUnit should I use? [In this post](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/293681/phpunit-errors-occur-when-running-drupal-check) kiamlaluno answered that Drupal 9 supports PHPUnit 8 at the moment; therefore, I think that version 8.5 is OK, isn't it?

I installed PHPUnit 8.5.8 with composer, but when I try to use it, I get this error.

> Class "Symfony\Bridge\PhpUnit\SymfonyTestsListener" does not exist.

[This post](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/269303/symfonytestslistener-does-not-exist-on-php-unit-test) suggest installing symfony/phpunit-bridge, Composer choose version 5.1, but it didn't work, and I got the same error message. Is this a wrong version for Drupal 9 and PHPUnit 8.5.8?
It solved the issue commenting out the listener class in phpunit.xml. But I'm not shure if this is the right way.

4. Is there anywhere a documentation/tutorial for the actual official release of drupal to get PHPUnit running the recommended way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*drupal/recommended-project* doesn't install PHPUnit, which is instead installed with the drupal/core-dev meta-package. For example, if I wanted to install Drupal 9.0.3, including PHPUnit, I would use the following commands.

```bash
composer create-project drupal/recommended-project:^9.0 my-project
cd my-project
composer require 'drupal/core-dev:^9.0'
```

As said in [Starting a Site Using Drupal Composer Project Templates / Adding drupal/core-dev](https://www.drupal.org/docs/develop/using-composer/starting-a-site-using-drupal-composer-project-templates#s-adding-drupalcore-dev), *drupal/core-dev* still doesn't depend on *drupal/core*. Specifying a version of *drupal/core-dev* is necessary to get a version that matches the Drupal core version you are using.
Also, if you want to install Drush, you need to first install *drupal/core-dev* and then *drush/drush*.

As for the PHPUnit version, *drupal/core-dev* 9.0.3 requires the following packages.

- phpspec/prophecy: ^1.7
- phpunit/phpunit: ^8.4.1
- symfony/phpunit-bridge: ^4.4

Using more recent version for *phpunit/phpunit* and *symfony/phpunit-bridge* hasn't been tested, yet.

For Drupal 8.8.0, *drupal/core-dev* 8.8.0 requires a version of *phpunit/phpunit*
that matches *^6.5 || ^7*, a version of *phpspec/prophecy* that matches *^1.7*, and a version of *symfony/phpunit-bridge* that matches *^3.4.3*.
Even with Drupal 8.8.0, installing PHPUnit after installing Drupal core with *drupal/recommended-project* requires the same steps I described for Drupal 9.

Comment: Thank you very much for this explanation. Would be nice to have a hint to drupal/core-dev at https://www.drupal.org/docs/automated-testing/phpunit-in-drupal/running-phpunit-tests. The core-dev package has installed phpunit 8.5.8, phpspec/prophecy 1.11.1. For now it seems to work. Should I downgrade to the packages you told?

Comment: I executed the commands I reported in this answer, in a directory I created, and I obtained the same package versions you got. It means they are fine, with the restrictions given from Drupal core.

Comment: If you install `core-dev` after having installed your site & modules, shouldn't you install also all dev dependencies for the modules you want to test ?